# Iterating through a Map of Map of Maps in Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have a map of a map of a map in firestore and I was wondering how I am able to through the inner values of the map?

This is what my structure looks like:
`map: {1: {1.1: asdasd, 1.2: asdasd}, 2: {2.1: qweqwe, 2.2: qweqwe}}}`

I've tried using a `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>`, but this gives me `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'`

Is there any way to resolve this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Looks like more a `Map<Map<>>` rather than a `Map<Map<Map<>>`

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out by just using `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`